# How to specify element without specific name

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to write a XML schema for my XML file. My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<styles>

  <style name="p">
    <text-indent>25px</text-indent>
  </style>

  <style name="td">
    <border>solid 2px</border>
    <border-color>Black</border-color>
    <padding-left>5px</padding-left>
  </style>

  <style name="p.withoutRedLine">
    <text-indent>0px</text-indent>
  </style>

</styles>
```

Every 'style' element can have items with **any** names.

I wrote the next XML schema (problems are defined in code comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns="http://www.mia-orbis.com/2012/XMLSchema/styles"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:complexType name="style">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <!--Error in it place (I don't need to specify value 
      of attribute 'name', but from me it demand):-->
      <xsd:element type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>    
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="styles">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="style" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xsd:any:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xsd:complexType name="style"> 
        <xsd:sequence> 
            <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
        </xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/> 
    </xsd:complexType> 
    <xsd:element name="styles"> 
        <xsd:complexType> 
            <xsd:sequence> 
                <xsd:element name="style" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="style"/> 
            </xsd:sequence> 
        </xsd:complexType> 
    </xsd:element> 
</xsd:schema>
```

I did some fixes to your schema: removed the default namespace, set the type to the style element, etc.

If you agreed to use xsd:any already, it may prove good practice to define what you know, and leave xsd:any for anything else.

Comment: It is not work too. Error in row:
<xsd:element name="style" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="style"/>

Comment: @Bush, the XSD I posted is perfectly valid; what tool are you using to validate it?

Comment: Forgive me, I was mistaken yesterday. Probably incorrectly copied a code.

But it schema not correct for me. For example, she resolves also such data:
`code`
  <style name="p">
 <text-indent>25px</text-indent>
 <ttt>
   <sss>sss</sss>
 </ttt>
  </style>
`code`

Comment: @Bush, well, you said `Every 'style' element can have items with any names.` ttt is just one of them... I am afraid you have to decide what you want first. If you seeing my quote makes you rethink your approach, you might consider building a bunch of XMLs that show exactly what you need, then use [a tool](http://paschidev.com) that could take in more than one XML to create an XSD and start from there instead.

Comment: Forgive, I didn't mention that the element can have any name, but it item must have only the 'string' type.